# Expectation of $|H - T|$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Using binomial approximation to normal distribution, find the expectation of $|H-T|$ where the $H,T$ are heads and tails of a fair coin and the number of tosses is large. Can anyone please tell me, how to approach the expectation of an absolute value?

Comment: Mod function? What means mod? If we throw 20 times the coin, what is the probability that $|H-T|=5$? And $|H-T|=21$?

Comment: $$|X| = X1_{X \ge 0} - X1_{X < 0}$$. if $X(\omega_1) = -10$, then $|X|(\omega_1) = (-10)(0) - (-10)(1)$ if $X(\omega_2) = 100$, then $|X|(\omega_2) = (100)(1) - (-100)(0)$

Comment: You have to improve your question. What is the mod function in this context ? Or do you mean the $\color{red}{\text{absolute value}}$ ?

Comment: A side comment:  I think the expectation seems to be the same with $2k-1$ tosses as with $2k$ tosses, in both cases marginally higher than $\sqrt{\dfrac{4k-1}{\pi}}$

Comment: And the exact expectation for $n$ tosses seems to be $\dfrac{(2\lceil n/2\rceil-1)!}{\left((\lceil n/2\rceil-1)!\right)^2 4^{\lceil n/2\rceil-1}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n$ is the number of tosses, then $T=n-H$, so $H-T=2H-n$.

Since $n$ is large, $H$ has a close to normal distribution, mean $n/2$, and variance $(n)(1/2)(1/2)$. So $2H-n$ has close to normal distribution, mean $0$ and variance $n$.

Let $W$ be a normal with mean $0$ and variance $n$. Let us find the mean of $|W|$. This is
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{|w|}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}e^{-w^2/(2n)}\,dw.$$
By symmetry, the above integral is 
$$2\int_{0}^\infty \frac{w}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}e^{-w^2/(2n)}\,dw.$$

Comment: $$W = 2H-n = T-H$$ ?

Comment: @BCLC: $2H-n$ is "approximately" normal with known mean and variance. Let $W$ be a normal random variable with that mean and variance. (It would be better to work with the version scaled to variance $1$.) Certainly $2H-n$ is not normal, it has a discrete distribution.

Comment: I think that integral is $\sqrt{\dfrac{2n}{\pi}}$

Comment: @Henry: Integrand fixed, and yes, that's what it turns out to be.